# checking if array has data with if statement not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

I am trying to see if my nsarray has data before I gray out cell text - but for some reason it's blowing up on the if evaluation with the dreaded SIGBRT... the following code is works fine if the key 'myIndex' exists ...I delete the key when the user sends his orders in at the end of the app....so when the app opens after an order I would like to skip ?????

```
if(![[[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"] count] == 0){

       NSArray *myIndexList = [[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"];
       NSLog( @"data from INDEX !!!!!!!! %@", myIndexList);

       for(int n=0; n<[myIndexList count]; n++)
       {
           if(indexPath.row == [[myIndexList objectAtIndex:n] integerValue])
           {
               cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
           }
       }

   }
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What's the associativity of `!` vs `==`?  Did you know that there's a `!=` operator?

Comment: yeah tried that != no luck I guess I was just experimenting, thx.   By the way the error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'

Comment: Do you know how to use NSLog?

Comment: Keep in mind that you'd get that error if `inList` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that there is an object in inList first:

```
if ([inList count] > 0) {
    if([[[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"] count] > 0) {
        // there is a valid object
    }
}
```

Comment: things just got strange...this works insofar as I can now open the app with an empty array; however, when I push to a second view and then hit the back button to go back to my root view the app moves the nav bar but not the view.....so I it seems I can not go back ????? stuck on my second view...my detailsView....thx ???????

Comment: What is your code for navigating back and fourth with your views ?

Comment: I am using a Master\Detail Template the back button appears automatilly in the nav bar when ever I push a new viewController

Comment: Well, this code doesn't do anything with navigation...  I'd suggest asking a different question (and including the relevant code) if you need help with that!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the object exists like this:

```
if([[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex")
{
    //It exists, do something (otherwise ignore it)
}
```

Comment: tried this to no luck same error (more info: I have this code in my cellforrowatIndexPath), thx

Answer (score 0):

To check if a NSArray has data on a specific object:

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [inList objectAtIndex:0]] length] == 0) {
    //Do somthing if the NSArray object is empty.
} else {
    //Do somthing if the NSArray object countains somthing.
}
```

To check if any object in NSArray has data:

```
for (int count = 0; count < inList.count; count++) {
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [inList objectAtIndex:count]] length] == 0) {
        //Do somthing if the NSArray object is empty.
    } else {
        //Do somthing if the NSArray object countains somthing.
    }
}
```